# how to handle navigation on map annotation bubble

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I trying to create an application which will show some location on map. When i click on bubble with location name, i want to navigate to different view which will some information regarding the selected location
Can anyone guide me how to do that..

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Umang why don't to you try adding a `UIButton` to the `MKPinAnnotationView` and give it a action that will be much easier. Navigate to diffetrent view by the action of UIButton......Please have a look on [this tutorial](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/) and see how the `UIImageView` and `UIButton` is added to the `MKPinAnnotationView`

good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MKMapView delegate method

```
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
        // navigate to view from here
}
```